# Power Automate cannot connect to Logic Apps via http action

Tags: http, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

In my company we have a Power Automate Flow, which at first receives a string (being an article number) from a Power Apps app, that is entered by the user.
This String in turn is supposed to be sent to a Logic Apps app by usage of a HTTP GET action:
[image]

As you can see, this request fails to work and the error details say, that the server hasn't received a response from the upstream server. I guess, this would be the Logic Apps app? Below is an image of this app:

[image]

This setup used to work untill a couple of months ago. I might add, that I inherited this app from my predecessor, so I wonder, if some subscription ran out.

I hope, someone has an idea, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Logic App, then you should take a look at the previous runs (under Runs History). Like the Flow Run History in Power Automate which lets you see how a flow executed, Logic Apps have an equivalent.

As much of the (important) inner workings of the Logic App likely lies within the Condition block, it's hard to pinpoint an exact cause from the screenshot alone. I suggest having a look at that so that you have a better indication on what / where / how to troubleshoot the actual problem

I would've posted this as a comment but I don't have the reputation points for that yet

Comment: Hi Tinus Smit,

Yes, I know about the history in Logic Apps. There you can see well, that it worked flawlessly untill June first before noon but on the same day afternoon is when it started to fail constantly.
Looking at the fails, I can actually see, that the Logic Apps app indeed receives data from the Power Automate Flow, so I was wfong on that, I must admit. What he fails at is the execution of a SQL command, where data is retrieved. According to the error message, the token is expired and if he doesn't retrieve any date, there is also nothing to be sent back to the PA Flow...

Comment: There's a few things that you can do here.
- Update the Logic App with the latest token so that the SQL step can execute.
- Update the Logic App with a parallel action that runs when the previous step fails. There you can add another Response action with a different message that's more meaningful.

It seems that some refactoring is required to handle errors more gracefully in the Logic App and Power Automate flow. There's not a a lot more detail I can provide in the space of a comment box here, but this ought to address the immediate problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that you are using HTTP Get action but you need to use HTTP post in order to send the string to logic apps.

Here is a sample that you can refer to

Flow in my power Automate

[image]

Flow in my Logic App

[image]

### Results:

In Power Automate

[image]

In Logic Apps

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to solve the issue: I simply had to set up a new SQL connector and now it works smoothly again.
Also, my predecessor typed the filter of the http get wrongly:
[image]

"table" was missing, although it is supposed to be used in the Logic Apps app.