# How to pass string from PowerAutomate to Logic Apps?

Tags: httprequest, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I want to send a string to Logic Apps from Power Automate. In my company there are two set ups like this, so I know it's doable.
In the logic app, I seem to be able to somehow pass it (name: Group), as one can see in the initialize variable module:
[image]

In the Power Automate flow, I try to pass the string "G2" like this:
[image]

However, the string is always empty:

[image]

I really tried to rebuild this set up like the other apps we have, but haven't been successful so far. Anyone has experience in that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end you can send the string utilizing the body of the HTTP Trigger using a JSON body. Below is the flow in my PowerAutomate.

[image]

Here is the code in my Logic apps

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

For reproducing in your environment you can use the below codeview in your logic apps

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Group",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@triggerBody()?['Group']"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Group": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi SwethaKandikonda-MT,

I'll give it a try..

Comment: It's me again: It worked! Thanks a lot!
I still don't get, how the h*** my coleague set it up, but in the future, I will use youre method.

Cheers

Comment: @MilanPijanovic, Glad that it helped. You can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133252/power-automate-cannot-connect-to-logic-apps-via-http-action In cases where you send a string without any payload or json in your flow

Comment: SwethaKandikonda-MT,

You really made my day! I got stuck in a project, but now I have made progress. 
I wonder how one can extend the scheme to pass more than one string. Would it look something like that?
{
"Group": "SomeGroup",
"Example": "SomeExample"
}

Comment: @MilanPijanovic , Yes you are right.